# При нажатии на картинку страница "уходит" на верх

Tags: html, css

Вот код страницы

```
<section>
    <ul id="gallery">
        <li id="fullPreview"></li>

        <li>
            <a href="images/p1.jpg"></a>
            <img data-original="images/t1.jpg" src="img/effects/white.gif" alt="Фото 1">
            <div class="overLayer"></div>
            <div class="infoLayer">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h2>Заголовок фото</h2>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>Краткое описание изображения</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="projectInfo">
                Полное описание изображения
            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

При нажатии на p1.jpg загружается полное изображение t1.jpg, все здорово, картинка загружается в пределах section../section, но вся страница перемещается в самое начало. Если пролистать вниз, дойти до  - можно просмотреть оригинал фото. Если загруженный оригинал закрыть и нажать повторно на p1.jpg перемещения в начало страницы уже не происходит... Как можно побороть данный баг?

Comment: судя по приведенному фрагменту кода, тут вообще ничего не нажимается никуда.

Comment: но на практике нажимается)

Comment: тут можно ссылки выкладывать? я бы показал как это работает...

Comment: можно выкладывать. но небось на практике у вас еще JS код какой-то имеется, который этим управляет.  У вас в коде есть картинка. Сам по себе клик на картинке ничего не делает. Есть ссылка на картинку, но она пустая. Даже если бы вы ее смогли нажать, то у вас открылась новая страница с указанной в ссылке картинкой. Так что повторюсь, проблема не в данном коде. Вопрос не состоятелен.

Comment: JS имеется... только опыта работы со скриптами не очень много((